# JAVA_HOME can support x86 and x64 both together?

Tags: java, windows, java-home

My OS is win7 x64, and java.com recommend that using java x86 version in your OS x64 or you can install x86 and x64 both in your OS, but the path of Java_Home (JDK or JRE) can using the x86 and x64 at the same time?

sorry for the page is Chinese...
https://www.java.com/zh_TW/download/faq/java_win64bit.xml

Answer (score 0):

Your path can include as many versions as you like however only the first version in your PATH will be the one chosen.  This is how a PATH work. On all operating systems.  This is how the class path also works.

I recommend using the x64 where ever possible on an x64 operating system because unless you have 32-bit DLLs, or running Java in a 32-bit browser, you are better off using the x64 version.

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for your answer. I think it could be a solution before 32-bit  end.